# Bluetooth Paircode Issue - DualShock 4 Wont Pair

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have a DualShock 4 controller (DS4). It wont pair with my bluetooth dongle.

I figured out that the problem is in Windows not letting me type in a passcode.

How do I force that?

Comment: My understanding is the DS4 requires a special wireless adapter on the PC or you can connect via USB.  What makes you believe the DS4 should simply connect via BT?

Comment: No, it does not require. I dont have 600CZK/20$ to spend, so i need to use this. If you google it you will see that just Pressing the PS and Share button enables bluetooth pairing. Phone works fine, so i play SMW on the go, but computer refuses to let me enter in a pair code.

Comment: Indeed, the DS4 doesn't need anything except a regular Bluetooth connection. I think the confusion is in the fact that XBOX One controllers currently need [special dongles that only work with Windows 10](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/adapters/wireless-adapter-windows) to connect wirelessly to PC (as odd as it sounds). And the alternative is just to connect them via USB cable (though the the DS4 can do that too.)

Comment: @Anaksunaman -  I wasn't confused by anything, Sony released an adapter for the PC, I figured there was a reason.  Xbox One controllers no longer require a "special dongle", starting with the Xbox One S, the newer controllers support BT.

Comment: @Ramhound Lol! I guess I am a just a *little* behind the times there. Appreciate the update . =)

Answer (score 2):

## Pairing the DS4 with Windows 7 over bluetooth

While this could be done with a wire or dongle, [HowToGeek reports](https://www.howtogeek.com/240152/how-to-use-a-playstation-4s-dualshock-4-controller-for-pc-gaming/) that this is possible without the dongle sold by Sony:

> To wirelessly connect your PlayStation 4 controller with a PC without any additional hardware, you’ll need to put it in Bluetooth pairing mode.

However, note the word of caution in the next sentence:

> **Many people report the controller’s Bluetooth connection can be a bit flaky on PC**, depending on your Bluetooth chipset and drivers, so you may want to use a wired connection or an official wireless adapter if you experience problems.

*(emphasis mine)*

### Put the controller into pairing mode

- Hold the <kbd>PS</kbd> button down to turn the controller off
- Hold the <kbd>PS</kbd> and <kbd>Share</kbd> buttons together until the light bar starts flashing

### Pair with Windows

This can be done via:

1. `Control Panel`
2. `Devices and Printers`
3. `Add a device`

The controller *shouldn't need a pairing code*, but `0000` can be entered if prompted.

### Troubleshooting

Unfortunately, though lots of people are able to pair okay, the process fall down for others. Xaero on the [PCSX2 forums has a few suggestions](https://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-Associating-a-DualShock-4-controller-with-Windows-7):

#### Reset all Bluetooth devices and settings.

> To do this, you must first uninstall your bluetooth adapter.
>
> ...
>
> Then, you'll need to remove the following keys from the registry - these are system protected keys, so you MAY NEED to install sysinternals, and follow an additional step. (**Before proceeding, click file, then export and save a backup to your desktop!**):
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\` → delete `BTHENUM` & `BTH`
>
> Reinstall your Bluetooth adapter

#### Disable the device permission dialog

> ** This feature of Windows 7 seems to be the main problem with the DS4 associating with a Windows 7 computer.**

*(emphasis mine)*

> 1. Click the Bluetooth icon in the taskbar (bottom right, you may have to click the arrow to reveal it)
> 2. Click Open Settings
> 3. In the settings window UNCHECK the box that says Alert me when a new Bluetooth device wants to connect (you can probably re-enable this later when all of your controllers are working)
> 4. Click "Ok"

#### Bluetooth driver or chipset issues

Other have [reported issues with bluetooth drivers, eg Qualcomm](https://pcpartpicker.com/forums/topic/187554-cant-pair-my-new-ps4-controller-to-pc-via-bluetooth)

> I had a few major issues using a PS4 controller with Qualcomm bluetooth devices. **So much so that on one board (Asrock FM2A88X-itx) I had to go get a $10 blue tooth usb card and use it**. Myy current board with has an Intel Bluetooth controller, it worked right off the bat.

Since you don't have the cash right now for the Sony dongle, you probably don't want to speculate on a new bluetooth adapter (though they should be cheaper than the Sony dongle). It may be worth borrowing a bluetooth USB dongle and seeing if that changes the issue. Otherwise, the often-useful advice applies: ensure the bluetooth device drivers are up to date.

Comment: Hm, for me the old DS4 that came with PS4 works and pairs correctly while the "new" one (CUH-ZCT2G) is not detected by my PC when searching for BT devices.

Comment: Interesting- is the new one genuine? I bought a DS3 that looks very real, but scpmonitor detects it as fake. Also, I should re-test this answer now that I have a DS4...

Comment: It looked genuine and Steam does detect it as DS4 when connected via usb along with PS4. I didn't try scpmonitor, however. If there are any other genuineness checks, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly the pairing problem for OP looked, but mine was like this on Windows 7: I do pairing on the usual way, you know, add new bluetooth device, hold Share+PS button until controller flashes, then the controller shows up, I allow the pairing, then Windows starts to install the driver automatically (from Windows Update), and even says that it succeeded. But then, I notice that the controller is turned off (its LED is off), and when I turn it back on (by pressing PS key), Windows will again ask permission for the pairing, and starts to install the device driver again, which succeeds, but the controller is turned off again, and if you turn it back on, above cycle will repeat forever.

If you keep the "Devices and Printers" control panel window open during this process, you will see that the Wireless Controller appears in it during installation, but then few seconds after the driver installation was successfully finished, it just vanishes. (The Wireless Controller should stay visible in that window even if it's off, so it's not because of that.) And so, when you turn the controller back on, it's indeed a new device, because something just deleted its last "installation".

**The solution** I found: As the installation process is going on, when the LED of the controller is turned off, then immediately(!) press the PS button to turn it back on. It will be turned off again and again, but be persistent, and turn it back on. At a point (near the end of driver installation?) it will stay turned on. And now, the Wireless Controller won't vanish after the installation, and since then it stayed there.